# Rounding and getting a count of the number of times a number appears? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
-1.25
-0.5
   0
   0
1.25
0.75
1.25
   2
   2
   2
   2
```

I'm trying to consolidate these numbers while also rounding them, and making anything that is negative go to 0.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    RawScore,
    Count(*) AS Freq
FROM TestScores
GROUP BY RawScore
```

This returns

```
RawScore    Freq
-1.25        1
-0.5         1
   0         2
0.75         1
1.25         1
   2         4
```

Is there a way to get this instead?

```
RawScore    Freq
     0        4
     1        2
     2        4
```

Comment: Use a case expression to change negative values to 0. And then look at the ROUND function for rounding.

Comment: You should have `3` for `Freq` of `1` -- or `5` for `Freq` of `0`, depending on if you are rounding or truncating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select (case when rawScore < 0 then 0
             else round(rawScore, 0)
        end) as nolongerrawScore,
       count(*)
from TestScores
group by (case when rawScore < 0 then 0
               else round(rawScore, 0)
          end) 
order by nolongerrawScore;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks. 

I like how you pointed out that it's no longer a raw score.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    FLOOR(ABS(RawScore)),
    Count(*) AS Freq
FROM TestScores
GROUP BY FLOOR(ABS(RawScore))
```